# Confusion about valid set of virtual displacement

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, string, constrained-dynamics

The answer of the problem below makes me confused about my thinking about virtual displacement...

Consider the system in the figure below, similar to mechanisms used for aerial filming of sporting events. The system consists of four actuated spools fixed in the world frame that control cables suspending a payload above the field by controlling d1−d4. In our example, consider these four spools to be fixed to the corners of the ceiling of a rectangular room. When viewed from above, the camera must stay inside the rectangle prescribed by the walls of the room. Assume that all cables must remain taut and that the intersection of the four cables is to be confined to a horizontal plane of constant altitude at all times. In addition to this cable system, the pan (θ1) and tilt (θ2) of the camera are controlled by motors as shown below.
[image]

Consider a configuration in which d1 = d2 = d3 = d4, the tilt of the camera is set so as to be level, and the pan is set in an arbitrary direction. Below is a set of conditions restricting the sign of some virtual displacements for the system. For each condition, check the box if there exists an infinitesimal motion [δd1, δd2, δd3, δd4, δΘ1, δΘ2] satisfying this condition that is also a valid set of virtual displacements. Note that we have not directly constrained the values of the displacements of other coordinates not mentioned below, other than the constraints imposed on the overall system throughout this exercise.

So the answer is:

δd1 > 0, δd2 > 0

δd1 < 0, δd2 < 0

δd1 > 0, δd3 > 0

while "δd1 < 0, δd3 < 0" is wrong, I have no idea how this makes sense

Comment: Hint: what happens to the other two cables when you tighten two opposite ones?

Comment: The camera will rise up? As to meet d1 = d2 = d3 = d4, cable 24 also tighten up at the same time?

Comment: Hint: will the other two cables remain taut?

Comment: They won't? Guess that's what I am confused about now...

Comment: Hint: Look at your assumptions.

Comment: Okay I don't know if this is right or not:  for δd1 > 0, δd2 > 0 / δd1 < 0, δd2 < 0, the side view of the d3 d4 could remain the same length as they rotate a little bit, and the whole system reaches a new equilibrium. While δd1 < 0, δd3 < 0 will looses the d2 and d4, but I am still confused that when δd1 > 0, δd3 > 0, d1 and d3 will loose, right?

Comment: Hint: it says, right in the question, that the cables **must remain taut**, i.e. they are not allowed to be loose at any point in time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking... For δd1 < 0, δd3 < 0,  if δd2 and δd4 also < 0, then all of them still remain taut which brings the contradiction

Answer (score -1):

This problem was really mind twisting, but after seeing the answer I realised that we don’t need to think too much... just consider, which of the given 4 conditions will give you a point of intersection!
Just see this image...

[image]

Comment: Images are not accessible to all users. Please put the relevant information in as text.